# What is pb.conflict in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to find an optimal solution using the `Z3 API` for python. I have used `set_option("verbose", 1)` to print statements that `Z3` generates while checking for sat. One of the statements it prints is **pb.conflict** statements. The statements look something like this -
[pb.conflict statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN62S.png).

I want to know what exactly is **pb.conflict**. What do these statements signify? Also, what are the two numbers that get printed along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pb` stands for Pseudo-boolean. A pseudo-boolean function is a function from booleans to some other domain, usually `Real`. A `conflict` happens when the choice of a variable leads to an unsatisfiable clause set, at which point the solver has to backtrack. Keeping the backtracking to a minimum is essential for efficiency, and many of the SAT engines carefully track that number. While the details are entirely solver specific (i.e., those two numbers you're asking about), in general the higher the numbers, the more conflict cases the solver met, and hence might decide to reset the state completely or take some other action. Often, there are parameters that users can set to specify when such actions are taken and exactly what those are. But again, this is entirely solver and implementation specific.

A google search on pseudo-boolean optimization will result in a bunch of scholarly articles that you might want to peruse.

If you really want to find Z3's treatment of pseudo-booleans, then your best bet is probably to look at the implementation itself: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/smt/theory_pb.cpp